# How to get the response from email and set the action in Customer Insight- Journey

Tags: dynamics-crm, email-attachments, journey

We need to retrieve the response from the email and set the value of the option set field on the entity's form. In email When the user selects a value in the Optionset field on the form, the Email field value will be changed on the entity's form.

Can the value of a field on a form be changed by updating the embedded form in an email?
Are the Marketing form field and entity field the same thing?

Message me if you have any ideas about Customer Journey Insights, as it's new to me.
Thank you.

I created a journey to send emails. We included a link to the standalone Marketing form page in the email but it is not working on submit the form.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please visit the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research or search for related topics on SO. If you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.